# Why UILabel didn't display the assigned NSString's value?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uilabel

IN my project, I'm using UILabel and NSArray, I'm passing an argument from an array in the form of NSString, I've checked the method's call using breakpoint, the  argument  passing the argument correctly but while trying to use the received argument (in the from of NSString) but the UILabel display NULL value. Here is the code:

```
- (void)updateMenuLabel:(NSString *)passedObject {
   NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", passedObject];
   lbl_selectitem.text=str;

}
```

Comment: It's not connected properly in IB?  BTW the `stringWithFormat` line is redundant.

Comment: Connected with IBOutlet, remove the redundant line and tried but still  getting NULL

Comment: Make sure lbl_selectitem is not nil (log it with NSLog(@"%@",lbl_selectitem)).

Comment: If you are getting the word NULL in the label then the `passedObject` variable is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen because of several things: if this is a property, it hasn't been linked properly from the xib/nib file or storyboard. If this is has been created programmatically, have you checked it when you have assigned memory to this object? It´s clear the object is nil, but you have to notice where in the process. 
Put a break-point in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` (for example) to see if the object is still nil and go from there.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check passedObject string value. Print nslog the same value. As rckoenes suggested it is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you get NULL in interface, that means that string is nil.
If you can't see any changes, that means that string is empty (@"") or lbl_selectitem is nil. Maybe isn't connected to object in xib.

Add a breakpoint to first line. Then go to lldb console and type:

```
po lbl_selectitem
po passedObject
```

Values stored in properties would be printed and you can find a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

- Check if the string is nil/null when it is formatted.
- Make sure that if UILabel is an IBOutlet, it is declared as a property (@property).
  If not an IBOutlet, and if you are creating the UILabel, add to parent view using addSubview: method.